# access denied with srgs Grammar uwp speech reco

Tags: windows, uwp, grammar, speech

I try with this code  make a continuos recognition with SRGS Grammar.. but I have Error: "ACCESS DENIED" EXCEPTION in UWP APP.

I need make a method with out Dictation Grammar because I would like to use my app with out internet..

On WP8 you can use "Choices" whit a listGrammar.. But here is most Complicated.. SOmebody can help?

```
bool permissionGained = await CheckMicrophonePermission();
                                                if (permissionGained)
                        {

                            var languagenum = new Windows.Globalization.Language("es-ES");

                            string langTag = languagenum.LanguageTag;
                                                    SpeechRecognizer recognizernum = new SpeechRecognizer(languagenum);


                            texto = "       ..... ,,   Indique digito a digito el número telefonico";

                            SpeechSynthesisStream streamnum = await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);

                                                       await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(


                        () => { mediaElementrec.AutoPlay = true; mediaElementrec.SetSource(streamnum, streamnum.ContentType); mediaElementrec.Play(); ; ; }));

                                  this.speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(languagenum);
                                string fileName = String.Format("SRGS\\\\Grammar.xml", languagenum);
                                StorageFile grammarContentFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                            try
                            {



                                speechRecognizer.StateChanged += SpeechRecognizer_StateChanged;



                                SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
                                if (result.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
                                {

                                    sin.Voice = (SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Male));
                                    texto = "No se puede compilar el Archivo Grammar";
                                    SpeechSynthesisStream streamrec = await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);
                                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(


                                () => { mediaElementrec.AutoPlay = true; mediaElementrec.SetSource(streamrec, streamrec.ContentType); mediaElementrec.Play(); ; ; }));

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint grammarConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(grammarContentFile);
                                    speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarConstraint);
                                    SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilationResult = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
                                    await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
                                    speechRecognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2);
                                    speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;


                                    if (compilationResult.Status != SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
                                    {


                                        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Cant Compile Grammar");
                                        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
                                        speechRecognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.2);

                                        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;



                             }





                        }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if ((uint)ex.HResult == HResultRecognizerNotFound)
                            {
                                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                            }
                            if ((uint)ex.HResult == HResultRecognizerNotFound)
                            {

                                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Language not installed ");
                                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Dont have Permission Mic");
                        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

                    }
                        //**/

                        break;
```

Comment: Did you add the microphone capability in your appxmanifest?

Comment: Off course! jejeje is the principal mistake.. But i Have the same error. Im triying to do a method with a listgrammar and a loop.

Comment: Which code throw this exception? Is it possible your Grammars.xml file doesn't exist in your specified location?

Comment: Not, absolutly because when its ocurrs the message is: "File not found"